# How do you end up with commits that have no changed files?

Tags: git, github

I have three repositories, my local, my github and the project github.  My github is a fork of the project github.

I make my changes and push them to my github and then issue pull request to the project github.  Every so often I fetch from the project repository, merge into my github.

Normally when I'm done with this all three have the same history.  But this time my repositories one on one revision and the project is on another.

When I issue a pull request is says there are two commits but no changed files.  How does this happen?

Comment: Can we have a link to the pull request (if it's public, of course)? Or maybe you can post the current diff GitHub shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking that the situation is as follows:

You have 2 commits that the project repo doesn't have, which are therefore being picked up as the commits eligible for the pull request.

However, when the files are compared, there  is no difference between the final state of the files as of your second commit vs the current state of the files in the project repo.

So I'm guessing that your two commits are a change and then a reversal of that change, which has effectively restored the files to the state they were at before the first of your commits - i.e. the same state as they are in the project repo.